# Excel data validation rules don't follow sorting

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation

I am developing a program which creates a Excel file which uses data validation rules for drop-down list. My excel looks like the following pictures. Each cell has a different drop-down list.

[image]
[image]

But I noticed that such rules don't follow after sorting. It still remains the same cells.
I hope they should be aligned to the rows. Are there any good ways to solve the problem?

[image]

I found a similar question. But the solution does not work for my case.  The solution is one value validation rule which can be applied to a whole column with some IF conditioning rules. In my case, each cell has a different list and impossible to apply to the whole column.

[Sorting fails to move data validation rules along with data in Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/461363/sorting-fails-to-move-data-validation-rules-along-with-data-in-excel)

Comment: "...the solution does not work for my case." What, exactly, does not work in the solution you link to?

Comment: The solution is one value validation rule which can be applied to a whole column with some IF conditioning rules. In my case, each cell has a different list and impossible to apply to the whole column.